# PHP DOMImplementation XML DTD for Google Merchant Center

Tags: php, xml, dom, doctype

I'm using PHP and `DOMImplementation` to create a new XML file for use with the Google Merchant Center. I'm using RSS 2.0.

I would like to use the [validate](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.validate.php) method to check the file after I've created it. For this to work I think I need a doctype adding to the XML. I've found [createDocumentType](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domimplementation.createdocumenttype.php) which looks good, but I don't know what to add. Here is what I have:

```
$imp = new DOMImplementation();
$dtd = $imp->createDocumentType('channel','???','???');
$dom = $imp->createDocument('1.0', '', $dtd);
```

I don't know what to put where the question marks are above. At the moment it produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE channel PUBLIC "???" "???">
```

I think the first parameter is the root XML tag (in my case it is 'channel'). But from the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domimplementation.createdocumenttype.php) I don't know what to use for `publicId` and `systemId`.

**UPDATE**

To be clear, I'm really asking which DTD should I use for Google Merchant Center RSS XML files?

Comment: What is the DTD you want to use? You need to have some reference to that, otherwise you're most likely using something you don't need to use. (e.g. you might want to validate, but you need a DTD. If you don't have a DTD, you *can't* validate, even if you want so much).

Comment: Thanks hakre... I don't know which DTD to use, I guess that's what I'm asking really. What DTD should I use for a Google Merchant Center RSS XML file...?

Comment: Then I'd suggest you ask for that clearly in your question. Because otherwise users reading your question might click it but they expect something different here (you can edit your question to improve it).

Comment: Title and question updated! Is that better? Now that I've been clearer, any ideas..?

Comment: Quick googling revealed: https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/160589?hl=en , https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/160567 and https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/merchant-center/NRafc9aRwOM/2vVxqHyvJQsJ - maybe there is something to dig for you? And I also put the keywords in the title that this is about google merchant center.

Comment: I had already done some searching, hence this question on stack. I've already seen the first two links which don't mention doc types (which is what my question relates to). The third one is a good find, thank you, and tells me as of 2 years ago Google probably didn't offer a DTD. I might post directly on the Google forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered nicely on a Google forum post: https://www.en.adwords-community.com/t5/Google-Shopping-PLAs-Merchant/Merchant-Center-Feed-DTD/m-p/371198

Short answer: There is no DTD available from Google for their Merchant Center XML feeds, so you can't use PHP's built in `validate` method.